# PHP/WP custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom field in WP that isn't always required and can therefore be left blank. However, the custom field has a word preceding it in the HTML that I'd like to not show if the custom field is left blank.

I think there should be some sort of if/else statement, but am unsure of the exact syntax to get it working.

Code:

```
    <li><span>DATE:</span>
    <?php $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true);
      if (!empty($meta_value)) {
      echo '<li>'. $meta_value .'</li>';
      } ?>
    </li>
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Without the code block in question it would be hard for any of us to guess.

Comment: Can you paste into your question the code and HTML where it is being output?

Comment: You mean if there is no meta value. It will still show the `<span>` with the word DATE in it?

Answer (score 0):

You could put in your if statement what the pre-pended value would be. Let's say it was a $ and a space character.

`if (!empty($meta_value) || $meta_value != '$ ') {`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your `if` statement out wider a bit:

```
  $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true);
  if (!empty($meta_value)) {
    echo '<li><span>DATE:</span>'
    echo '<li>'. $meta_value .'</li>';
    echo '</li>';
  }
```

Though, your HTML looks a little astray (you have a list item inside a list item)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All i actually needed to do was to add the span after the initial echo'<li>, like such:

        echo <li><span>DATE: </span>. $meta_value .</li>

and yes, thank you for also pointing out i had an unecessary list item!

Cheers